# Get circles coordinates from image in MATLAB

Tags: excel, image, matlab, export

I am trying to get an excel file with x\y coordinates of circles to work in CAD afterwards.
Could anyone point out how to do it after I identified all of the circles?

My current code is the following:

```
im = imread('VPB.png');

%call imfindcircles
[centres,radii] = imfindcircles(im,[5,25]);
%display detected circles
imshow(im);viscircles(centres,radii);

% sort by y coordinate
[~, index] = sort(centres(:,2));  % 1 instead of 2 would sort by x coord
centres = centres(index, :);
radii = radii(index, :);

% display the ordering
imshow(im);
viscircles(centres, radii);
for c = 1:length(radii)
    text(centres(c,1), centres(c,2), sprintf('%2u', c));
end
```

[image for analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SCdg.png)

Comment: You have identified the circles, and know their centres and radii. So, what's your question exactly? What's failing or missing?

Comment: I need to export the centers coordinates of these circles, but do not know how, unfortunately. I need some minor update of the code to do that, but I do not know which exactly.

Comment: I see. Maybe [`writematrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) can help